# du with --max-depth, only show that depth level directories

Tags: du

With this command

```
du / -d 2
```

I get listed both depth 1 and depth 2 directories

```
/home
/home/john
/usr
/usr/lib
```

Is there a way to only show `max-depth` level directories? In the present case just

```
/home/john
/usr/lib
```